# 'useTable' is not exported from 'react-table'

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm getting this error when trying to use react-table .

'useTable' is not exported from 'react-table'.
My react-table version is "react-table": "^6.11.4" and react version is "react": "^16.8.4"

Comment: can you show us how are you doing the import?

Comment: import {useTable} from 'react-table'

Answer (score 1):

[useTable](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useTable.md) seems to be part of the docs in latest release (master), but for [v6 releases docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6/docs) it does not appear to be  there. Try updating to a [newer version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) (but keep in mind they are still in beta for v7)

Answer (score 0):

react-table switched to hooks in v7, you won't get them out of v6.

Comment: Hi, thank you for letting us know. But what does it mean in practice? :) How to deal with it / solve it? Thank you

Comment: you could upgrade to v7?